# Value of det(A), given trac(A), trac(A^2) and trac(A^3)

Tags: matrices

> If $A=[a_{ij}]_{n \times n}$ and

> $\text{trac(A)}=10$ and

> $\text{trac}(A^2)=28$ and

> $\text{trac}(A^3)=46$

> Then $\text{Det(A)}$ is

Let we have $A=\text{diag}[d_1,d_2,\cdots \cdots ,d_n]$

is an diagonal matrix of order $n\times n$

So here  $\displaystyle d_1+d_2+\cdots +d_n=10\cdots  (1)$

And $A^2=\text{diag}[d^2_1,d^2_2,\cdots \cdots ,d^2_n]$

So here $d^2_1+d^2_2+\cdots\cdots+d^2_n=28\cdots (2)$

And $A^3=\text{diag}[d^3_1,d^3_2,\cdots \cdots ,d^3_n]$

So here $\displaystyle d^3_1+d^3_2+\cdots\cdots+d^3_n=46\cdots (3)$

Now I did not understand how do I find

$d_1,d_2,\cdots d_n$ so that I  find value of $d_1d_2d_3\cdots d_n$

please have a look on that

Comment: Do we know that $A$ is $3×3$? The question would seem to be underdetermined otherwise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We need to know the matrix is $3×3$. Otherwise the problem is underdetermined. I make that assumption in the following solution.

We are to find the product of the eigenvalues $a,b,c$, using the fact that the trace is the sum of the eigenvalues. So we have

$a+b+c=10$ Eq. 1

$a^2+b^2+c^2=28$ Eq. 2

$a^3+b^3+c^3=46$ Eq. 3

Square Eq. 1 and subtract Eq. 2. This leads to the sum of pairwse products:

$ab+ac+bc=36$ Eq. 4

Next, render the factorization

$a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc=(a+b+c)[(a^2+b^2+c^2)-(ab+ac+bc)]$

Using the values from Eqs. 1 through 4 this becomes

$46-3abc=10×(28-36)$

from which $abc=42$. This product would then be the determinant of the assumed $3×3$ matrix.